# Saving to file, can't read double

Tags: java, collections

I have this code to save my collection to file and it's formatted as showed before.

```
{   
    try {
    PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter(path);
    //writing collection to file 
    for(film f: films)      
    { 
    save.printf("%s%n",f.title);

    save.printf("%d %d %f%n", f.marks, f.numberofmarks, f.average);}

    save.close();
    return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {return false;}

}
```

the structure of saved file looks like this:

```
pokemon

20 7 2.857143
```

I read from the file with the following code

```
{
    //opening scaner and taking care of ioexceptios

    FileReader fr= null;
    Scanner sc = null;

    try {fr = new FileReader(path);} 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {return false;}

    sc = new Scanner(fr);

    while(sc.hasNext()){ 
        film tmp = new film();              //creating new object 
        tmp.title = sc.nextLine();          //reading whole line and adding title
        tmp.marks = sc.nextLong();          //2nd line "marks" are read from and added to object
        tmp.numberofmarks = sc.nextLong();  // 2nd value is number of marks ,read and added to object 
        tmp.average = sc.nextDouble();      // last value (3rd) is average,read and added to object

        films.add(tmp);                     //adding the object with read fields to database
         sc.nextLine();                     //moving the scanner to next line

    }

    sc.close();                             //closing scanner
    return true;                            //returning true is everything happened according to plan 
}
```

Every time I get the error of input missmatch on `nextdouble()` when the value is a `Double`

Comment: which Locale do you use?Possible you using not US locale, and that's the reason

Comment: where do i check that ?

Comment: Surely those final `n`s in the format strings should be `\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly locale settings. Convert your point to a comma, or place the following in your code and try again.

```
scan.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Typical mistakes you run in once and never forget. Comma's and points/dots are typical culture settings of the executing OS system. Good to code in OS culture independence in case the files are read on multiple (uncontrolled) client systems. Enjoy the next code challenge you run into :).